# How to use include.xml in haxelib libraries?

Tags: haxe, openfl, haxelib

I've noticed that when using `hxssl` library, the `hxssl.ndll` is not copied next to exe file when targeting windows..

So, I just copied it there and it worked, but I need to use `include.xml` file to auto-include the ndll file at compile time.

Can any one help me in this? or how to use `include.xml`? And what tags to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have figured this out already (it's quite an old question), but I may as well answer it for anybody else who has the same question. The tags you use in include.xml are the same as in OpenFL's project.xml. What it does is basically add onto the project.xml.

So for example, this would be the include.xml to include your .ndll file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project>
    <ndll name="hxssl" haxelib="hxssl" />
</project>
```

I haven't actually used this tag before myself, but I assume that `name` is the .ndll filename without the extension, and `haxelib` is the library where it is found.

You can find more info about the syntax and tags [here](http://www.openfl.org/documentation/projects/project-files/xml-format/).

Comment: Thank you, in fact I have decided not to use hxssl library as I already have https in openFL